# How big of a breaker for 3 phase?

Tags: three-phase

I'd like to buy 2 PDUs and choose the right circuit breaker for the circuit I'd put them on. Both PDUs are 30amp 3 phase and I'll be using 208V 3 phase power. Here is the power label.
[image: Power label]

What I don't understand is how many amps would be going through the 208V 3 phase connection. On the right it says no more than 51.9A and no more than 17.3A per phase.

Does that mean that each phase only pulls up to 17.3A and a 3 phase 20A or 30A breaker would be sufficient?

Comment: Have you got some installation manual?

Comment: I haven't bought the PDU's yet. Just trying to plan it out first. Don't wanna make any bad purchases.

Comment: Looks like total output is 51.9A (17.3 x 3) but the input is specified as 30A per phase so that’s what you’ll need.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like the input is somewhere between 20-30A per phase, otherwise this would be a 20A PDU? But the output is 17.3A/phase. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it self explanatory: You do need a 3x30A circuit breaker, but also you have to drag the cable of suitable cross-section. IN EU it would be 4x6mm^2, don't know for US regulative, but something close to that. ou do install the circuit breaker in the distribution box and drag the cable from that box.

EDIT:

You do have to provide a cable 3x?? (let's say 3x10AWG) that is capable of delivering a current of 3x30A, if a circuit breaker 3x30A is used, this is your responsibility. Then it is up to this device to further handle and redistribute the current in the safe way.

Comment: I know I'd have to follow the American Wire Gauge standard. But do I need to do an 80% derating, or is that already derated on the PDU? Also how many max amps would come through each phase of the PDU's input (from the breaker)?

Comment: @Fallen You don't need to derate if you have correctly sized the cable. It's 1:1 a 10AWG cable can handle 30A, so the CBR has to be. I don't know the other details since you didn't provide any manual of the device, probably it has its own fuses.

Comment: So there is no standard that you must derate so continuous load is < 80%? I intend to run 4x wires L-L-L-N to it of sufficient size from a 3P-N breaker. I was able to find this PDF of the device https://objects.eanixter.com/PD424844.PDF.

Comment: @Fallen Actually you need 3PH+PE and 3P breaker. NO NEUTRAL - there is no place you can connect it.  The PE has to be bound to the PE of the building in the distribution box, and never ever disconnected.

Comment: Oh ok. I got wye and delta confused and didn't know there was a difference. Since this is a delta input, that means I can't supply 208V to it right, only 240V?

Comment: @Fallen What makes you think you can't supply 208V 3-phase to it?

Comment: @SimonB The PDF (https://objects.eanixter.com/PD424844.PDF) says, under "Available Input Voltages", that this PDU takes "240V 3-Phase Delta, 50/60 Hz". And you can't supply 208V Delta right, only wye?

Comment: @Fallen But the label has both 240 and 200V ratings.  Realistically, the best thing you can do is ask the supplier.